# vert.x Reactive mySQL client query always give empty result

Tags: java, mysql, vert.x

I am working with java Vert.x project and connected to the MySQL using the Reactive MySQL Client using the guide of vert.x official [Documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mysql-client/java/). When I tried to retrieve data from `SELECT` query it always gives empty result even there are data in the DB. The method that was implemented to retrieve data is given below.

```
client.getConnection(conRes -> {
        if(conRes.succeeded()) {
          logger.info("Connected to DB !!!");
          SqlConnection conn = conRes.result();
          String query = "SELECT * FROM table where id ="+id;

          conn.query(query, res-> {
            logger.info("Query Executed for retrieve data, id: "+id);
            if(res.succeeded()) {
              RowSet<Row> result = res.result();

              if(result.size() > 0) { //Also tried with result.rowCount()

                Row rowRes = result.iterator().next();
                stringPromise.complete(rowRes.getString("reference_number"));

              } else {
                logger.error("No data reference number for id: "+id); // Always endup with here
                stringPromise.fail("No data reference number for id: "+id);
              }
              conn.close();
            } else {
              logger.error("Query executed failed due to "+res.cause().getMessage());
              res.cause().printStackTrace();
              stringPromise.fail(res.cause());
              conn.close();
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

Connection properties for the above method are,

```
MySQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
      .setPort(3306)
      .setHost(host_ip)
      .setDatabase(db_name)
      .setUser(username)
      .setPassword(password);

    // Pool options
    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions()
      .setMaxSize(5);

    client = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);
```

The method shows no errors, but always gives o result and shows `logger.error("No data reference number for id: "+id);`. What is the issue and how can I fix this issue.

Comment: I have removed the jdbc tag, as the Vert.x MySQL client is not JDBC, so the JDBC tag is not applicable to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Is your id a string? Because then you have to put it between apostrophes:

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM table where id='%s'", id);
```

Comment: No my ID is Integer

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to make a reproducer by either creating a small project or adding a test to the project? The code you put here seems normal to me.

Comment: I will try to add test.